# Sending notifications to people within a certain radius

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-notifications, android-location

I've been looking for a solution like this for bloody ages now. I have an app where you are sending some information from your phone which is pin pointed on to a map.

What I Need: When a person makes a new post of information I want a notification to be sent to any people within 100M of that person when they made the post. The notification will be to people with my app on their phone. Not to random people.

Is this achievable?

Thanks

Hemm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using latitude / longitude to identify locations, this page lists some formulas for converting coordinates to distance/bearing: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html